# Probability $X$ is less than mean

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X$ be a random variable with expected value $\mu$.  I need an upper bound on $\Pr( X < \mu )$.  All of the bounds I could find deal with something like $\Pr( X < \mu - a)$ and become trivial if $a = 0$.

In the particular case I am interested in $X$ is a finite sum of independent random variables, i.e. $X = \sum_i x_i$, $x_i \in \{0, 1 \}$, where $Pr( x_i = 1) = p_i, Pr( x_i = 0) = 1 - p_i$.

Additionally, I know that $\mu \ge 1$; I don't know if that makes a difference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $X$ is continuous & its distribution is symmetrical, $Pr(X<\mu)=.5$. Is it continuous? Is the distribution skewed?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about the non-continuous case. But even some discrete distributions will have this be 0.5, some more, some less (if the mean even makes sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your upper bound is 1 since (by way of contradiction) for any upper bound $p$ less than 1, a Bernoulli($\pi$) random variable, $X$, having $0 < \pi < p$ will have $\mbox{Pr}(X < \mu) > p$.

Answer (score 5):

There is not enough information to answer this question. *If* the variable is from a distribution that is not skewed, then the probability is 0.5. But some distributions are very skewed indeed; in your specific case, if all the independent random variables are skew, so will the sum be.

e.g

install.packages("moments")

```
library(moments)
set.seed(12901)
x1 <- rnorm(1000)
x1a <- exp(x1)
skewness(x1a)
x2 <- rnorm(1000)
x2a <- exp(x1)
x3 <- rnorm(1000)
x3a <- exp(x1)
xtot <- x1 + x2 + x3
xatot <- x1a + x2a + x3a
mean(xtot)
sum(xtot<mean(xtot))/length(xtot)
mean(xatot)
sum(xatot<mean(xatot))/length(xatot)
```

For xtot, the probability is about .5; for xatot, it is much higher.

Comment: One need not apply more than basic probability laws to come up with an albeit trivial answer to the question if they use some logic. See my answer.

Comment: If $X$ is symmetric _and_ continuous. As a counterexample, if $X \sim \text{Binomial}(6, 0.5)$, then $\text{CDF}_X(\mu) = 0.66...$. This issue arises for any even $n$.